# PDO: Making an execute statement dynamic...but not working

Tags: php, pdo

this should be easy...but I can't figure it out. If the following execute statement works at the end of an insert query.....

```
     $query->execute(array($this->visible_password, 
                           $this->hashed_password, 
                           $this->temp_hashed_password, 
                           $this->first_name, 
                           $this->last_name, 
                           $this->position, 
                           $this->location, 
                           $this->city, 
                           $this->email, 
                           $this->country, 
                           $this->institution, 
                           $this->interests, 
                           $this->profile_comment));
```

and

```
       $result =  join(", ", array_values($place_holder));
       echo $result;
```

gives

$this->visible_password, $this->hashed_password, $this->temp_hashed_password, $this->email, $this->first_name, $this->last_name, $this->position, $this->location, $this->city, $this->country, $this->institution, $this->interests, $this->profile_comment

then why doesn't this work.....

```
     $query->execute(array($result))
```

var_dump on placeholder gives...

```
   array(13) { 

 [0]=> string(26) "$this->visible_password" 
 [1]=> string(25) "$this->hashed_password" 
 [2]=> string(30) "$this->temp_hashed_password" 
 [3]=> string(15) "$this->email" 
 [4]=> string(20) "$this->first_name" 
 [5]=> string(19) "$this->last_name" 
 [6]=> string(18) "$this->position" 
 [7]=> string(18) "$this->location" 
 [8]=> string(14) "$this->city" 
 [9]=> string(17) "$this->country" 
 [10]=> string(21) "$this->institution" 
 [11]=> string(19) "$this->interests" 
 [12]=> string(25) "$this->profile_comment" }
```

$placeholder is an array...that takes the attributes ($attributes) of a class

```
            $place_holder = array();
            foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
            $place_holder[] = "&#36this->" . $key;
        }
```

I have been trying to make create user method in my user class abstract so I could use it in all my classes. I've been converting my site to PDO from mysqli (nightmare). Here is the method....

```
public function  pdo_create_test() {

  $attributes = $this->attributes();
  $att = array_keys($attributes);     
   $question_marks = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
            $question_marks[] = "?";
    }
   $place_holder = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
           $place_holder[] = "&#36this->" . $key;
        }
  $result = join(", ", array_values($place_holder));
  $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
  $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
  $sql .= ") VALUES (";
  $sql .= join(", ", array_values($question_marks));
  $sql .= ")";
  $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array($this->visible_password, 
                      $this->hashed_password, 
                      $this->temp_hashed_password, 
                      $this->first_name, 
                      $this->last_name, 
                      $this->position, 
                      $this->location, 
                      $this->city, 
                      $this->email, 
                      $this->country, 
                      $this->institution, 
                      $this->interests, 
                      $this->profile_comment));

                   }
```

Here is an update....(I have altered the placeholder to get the value as Bill said below)
I am also echoing the sql and the result of the placeholder to see what is says.

```
public function  pdo_create_test() {
  global $handler;
  $attributes = $this->attributes();
  $att = array_keys($attributes);
  $question_marks = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    $question_marks[] = "?";
    }
  $place_holder = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    $place_holder[] = $this->$key;
        }
  $result = join(", ", array_values($place_holder));
  $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
  $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
  $sql .= ") VALUES (";
  $sql .= join(", ", array_values($question_marks));
  $sql .= ")";
    echo $sql;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $result;
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($result));

}
```

for

```
             $user = new User;
             $user->visible_password = "Sam";
             $user->hashed_password = "Walsh";
             $user->pdo_create_test();
```

the output is

INSERT INTO users (visible_password, hashed_password, temp_hashed_password, email, first_name, last_name, position, location, city, country, institution, interests, profile_comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Sam, Walsh, , , , , , , , , , ,

but no entry into the database....don't see why...the other DB fields are set to NULL so this isn't an issue....

Comment: What does `$place_holder` contain? Post the output of `var_dump($place_holder);`.

Comment: Your `$place_holder` values are strings not variables, so your `join()` is also returning a string, not variables. How are you defining `$place_holder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `place_holder` variable contains, but I think this might be the reason.  [Join](https://www.php.net/function.join) is just another name for the [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function which returns a string.  Execute needs the actual physical input item.

From the PHP site on [execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for the array of input values:

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters
> in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as
> PDO::PARAM_STR.

**UPDATE**

As stated in comments, here is a function that will execute a SQL string using the given data object.  It would be best to separate this out into a couple of functions (create parameter array, bind parameters, ect), but I have put them all into one function for readability.

An example use of the function could be `executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id', array('id' => 1));`

```
function executeQuery($sql, $data) {
    //Assumed that $pdo is created and is a valid PDO object
    $params = array();
    preg_match_all('/:\w+/', $sql, $matches);
    //Loop through all the matches
    //Create an array that looks like: array(
    //  :id => 1, 
    //  :name => 'Me'
    //)
    foreach($matches[0] as $param) {
        $paramName = substr($param, 1);
        //If the item is not supplied in the data object, null will be used
        $params[$param] = isset($data[$paramName]) && !empty($data[$paramName]) ? $data[$paramName] : null;
    }
    //Pepare the SQL statement
    if(($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) !== false) {
        //Bind all parameters
        foreach($params as $param => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue($param, $value);
        }
        //Execute the statement
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood, but there surely must be a way to make this dynamic, no?

Comment: What sort of dynamic functionality are you looking for?  I will post something I've used in a few projects that make it a little easier.

Comment: I have been trying to make create user method in my user class abstract so I could use it in all my classes. I've been converting my site to PDO from mysqli (nightmare).

Comment: @GhostRider I have updated my answer with an example function to dynamically bind items to a given query.

Comment: OK, I'm going to study this and give it a go. Apologies if it takes me some time to come back with the outcome....

Comment: @GhostRider Not a problem.  I use something similar to this function in a few of my projects and have found that it helped me a lot by not having to manually write an array of data, an array of parameters, and make sure my query was formatted correctly.  There's some error checking that can be done along the way as well, but I left that out to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does have the concept of [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), so you can do this:

```
$varname = 'foo';

$foo = 123;

echo $$varname;
```

But this feature is limited. You can't apply it to all the elements of an array, nor can you use it with `$this->foo` notation for object variables.

You can use the variable variable syntax to get the *value* of your object variables corresponding to the attributes this way:

```
$place_holder = array();
foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    $place_holder[] = $this->$key;
}
```

Notice the `$key` after `->`. Normally object variable syntax does not have a `$` in that place. By using a `$` there, I'm telling it to get the value of the object variable whose name is the value of `$key`.

By the way, here's a more succinct (and probably faster) way to do the same thing:

```
$place_holder = array_intersect_key($attributes, get_object_vars($this));
```

---

Re your comment:

Well, first of all, you're doing this wrong:

```
$result = join(", ", array_values($place_holder));
```

This produces a single string with values separated by commas. It doesn't matter if you wrap it in `array($result)`, that just creates an array of a single string, even though the single string contains commas.

In other words, these two arrays are quite different:

```
array('A,B,C') // array with one element

array('A', 'B', 'C') // array with three elements
```

Instead, you need to pass to `execute()` is an array with the same number of elements as the number of `?` placeholders.

So just pass this:

```
$query->execute($place_holder);
```

Second, you need to check for errors after every `prepare()` or `execute()`:

```
if (($query = $handler->prepare(...)) === false) {
  print_r($handler->errorInfo());
}
if ($query->execute($result) === false) {
  print_r($query->errorInfo());
}
```

Or if that seems like too much coding, you could instead [enable PDO exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), and an error will cause your app to terminate with an error.

```
$handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Bill tried both of these...see my lower edit above...the output  suggests the right values are going in but nothing happening in the database...

Comment: You kind sir are a genius....although I did have to convert the array to an indexed array using array_values(). Thanks for the error tips as well...I am going to implement these.